# Batch scripting: Why does this condition evaluate to true?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10, command-prompt

Create a Batch file with the following contents:

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo %1
if [%1] == [] echo hi
```

Then run it from the command prompt like so:

```
script.cmd ==
```

It will output the following:

```
ECHO is off.
hi
```

Why is this, and how does it happen? Also, how can I more reliably check for empty strings in my batch scripts?

Thanks.

Comment: The core problem is that the `=` sign constitutes a token separator like also _space_, _tab_, `,` and `;`, so the script behaves as there was no argument given; putting it in between `""` abrogates their special meaning and keeps them literally; accessing the arguments with `%~1` removes the quotation marks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I suggest using the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo(%~1
if "%~1"=="" echo hi
```

And instead of `script.cmd ==` use `script.cmd "=="`

Note that I used `echo(` which will echo a newline if the variable is seen as empty, and that I used `%~1` which removes surrounding quotes from the `%1` argument.

You need the surrounding quotes because an [equal-sign is treated as a delimeter in the arguments](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/35938), unless inside quotes, just like spaces.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know about the `echo.` trick. Thanks for the concise/informative answer!

Comment: There was a huge discussion on Dostips, and `echo.` can have unintended results if there is a file called echo is the directory. It's better to use `echo(`.

Comment: @SomethingDark you're talking about [this](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774&start=0&hilit=echo+blank+line) I think? I had't read it before, but after reading it I agree that using `echo(` is indeed better.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I always forget about the whole "`echo/` for a blank line" part as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "cmdtail=%*"
ECHO(%cmdtail%
IF "%cmdtail%"=="==" ECHO two "="
```

But back to the unstated original problem.

Note that this syntax will detect the `==` provided as the command tail whereas `%~1` will not evaluate to `==`.